# Bash wrongly expands spaces into ';'

Tags: bash

I have a Tomcat7 installed from a JPackage RPM repository and a CentOS 6. When I run `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`, Bash generates a Java-invoking command that contains `';'` strings. Those strings break the Bash command.

Here is an example of a problematic command: `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:PermSize=128m ';' export -Dmykey=myvalue`.

Any idea what could cause Bash to insert those `';'` strings into the command? The Tomcat7 script itself should not cause the problem, because I have used the same Tomcat7 RPM package and its scripts successfully on other Linux instances.

Comment: Where is the actual code?

Comment: The code is in `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` and `/usr/sbin/dtomcat7` files of the Tomcat7 RPM.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by newline characters in `/etc/sysconfig/my_tomcat_instance`.

The file contained this snippet:

```
JVM_OPTS="-server -Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:PermSize=128m 
    -Dmykey=myval
    -Dmykey2=myval2
    "`
```

When I changed it into

`JVM_OPTS="-server -Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:PermSize=128m -Dmykey=myval -Dmykey2=myval2"`

my problem disappeared and I was able to start Tomcat7 normally.

**Lesson learned:** do not put newline characters into key-value pair files that Bash sources.

Comment: The "lesson" is misdirected. It's perfectly okay and sometimes necessary to have newlines - final or otherwise - in Bash strings. The semicolon was apparently added by something which had its own semantics for newlines in quoted strings (and implemented them weirdly, if not altogether incorrectly).